# How do you find the probability of A winning if the probability of getting a favourable outcome in the $r^{th}$ turn is a function of $r$?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, contest-math

**Problem:**

Two players A and B are playing snake and ladder. A is at 99 and he needs 1 to win in rolling of a dice. However, he is always allowed to re-throw the dice if 6 appears.

What is the probability that A will win eventually before B gets a chance, if the probability of getting 1 in the $r^{th}$ throw is $\frac{1}{3^r}$ and that of getting 6 in the $r^{th}$ throw is $\frac{2r-1}{4r}$?

**My attempt:**

We know that A can win before B gets a chance only if he rolls {$1$},{$6$,$1$},{$6$,$6$,$1$} and so on.

In the $r^{th}$ turn, we have the probability: $$\frac{1}{3^r}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{8}\cdot\cdot\cdot\frac{2r-3}{4(r-1)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{3^r}\cdot\frac{1}{4^{r-1}}\left(\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot\cdot\cdot(2r-3)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\cdot\cdot(r-1)}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{3^r}\cdot\frac{1}{4^{r-1}}\left(\frac{(2r-2)!}{(r-1)!\cdot(r-1)!\cdot2^{r-1}}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{24^{r-1}}\left(\frac{(2r-2)!}{(r-1)!\cdot(r-1)!}\right)$$

Therefore, we have the probability as

$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3}\cdot\binom{2r-2}{r-1} \frac{1}{24^{r-1}}$$

Taking $r-1$=$n$

$$\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{24^{n}}$$

---

I got stuck at the last step because I do not know how to evaluate that summation. Any help with the summation/providing an alternate way to solve this question will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The generating function for the *[central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)* is
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}z^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\qquad |z|<\frac{1}{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> This is an application of the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* 
>   \begin{align*}
> (1+z)^{\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}z^n\qquad |z|<1, \alpha\in\mathbb{C}
> \end{align*}
>   and the relation
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}
> \end{align*}

Can you proceed?

Comment: Thank you. I got the answer by this method. Do you have any alternative way of solving this question?

Comment: @AshishGupta: Your approach is fine and I would do it similarly. Here we have a *[geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)* which makes this approach quite natural. Maybe you could use *[double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)* to write some parts more compactly. E.g.: The second line could be written as $\frac{1}{3^r}\frac{1}{4^{r-1}}\frac{(2r-3)!!}{(r-1)!}$

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Just a minor question: I think it should be $|z|<1/4$?

Comment: @JimmyR.: Yes, of course!  Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @MarkusScheuer You are welcome :), +1

Comment: @MarkusScheuer No problem. Thanks for this answer. Waited till the last day only to see if someone could come up with an alternative way to solve the question :)